# How to force a shallow copy?

Tags: python

If I do this in a script

```
v = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data.vertices[0].co
```

`v` becomes a deep copy of that vector, this is a behaviour that is common to many other places inside the Python APIs.

The irony is that in Python the method [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html) returns a shallow copy, and [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html) returns a ... deepcopy; in Blender it looks like there is no real rationale for what you get, apparently everything is tuned for deep copies, but when an object has the `copy` method, it returns a deepcopy and not the standard python-esque shallow copy, and the method `deepcopy` is pretty much absent .

Inside loops you tend to get shallow copies because of Python optimizations, but speaking about the API in general, how I can enforce the use of shallow copies ?

Answer (score 1):

First sentence from the [link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html) provided in the question:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object

You assign / bind the `mathutils.Vector` object stored in the attribute `co` to the variable / name `v`.

You don't copy anything.

Use `co.copy()` to get a **new instance** of the vector and assign it to `v` instead.

Most vector operations and methods like `+`, `-`, `*`, `cross`, `dot` will also return a new instance for the result. So if you plan to use some of these maybe you don't need `.copy`.

This is done behind the scenes for immutable objects like strings or tuples. As soon as you make a change to a tuple or a string you get a new instance.

But if the object is mutable like a list it works the same way:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[0] = 4
a[0] #-> 4
```

Comment: there is no answer that is valid in Blender here. Blender's `copy` doesn't perform a shallow copy, I don't understand your wording or what you are trying to assert . if with _new instance_ you mean "deep copy" that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid .

Comment: The vector class has also the method `.is_wrapped` which tells you wether it has returned a shallow copy or not. In this case you can simply store a reference to the vertex itself ?

Comment: `is_wrapped` is probably the most useless thing in history for the simple fact that I can just try to modify the state of my variable and see if the supposedly linked object changes its own state at the same time. The point is that I want a shallow copy and a shallow copy only, I'm not looking for a way to check things. How to generate the reference you are talking about ? There is an operator ? For example in `C` there is the `&` which generates a pointer to `var` if written on the left `&var`, you mean something like that in python 3 ? How ?